# Use preg_replace with items from mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, regex

OK, so I'm not sure why but when i try to use `preg_replace()` on array items returned with `mysql_fetch_array()` I get no results but if I take those same results, make an array out of them it works fine.

Example

```
$pattern = '/^.*\b([0-9]{6}\s\D\d|[0-9]{6}\s\D[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{7}\s\D[0-9]{2})\b.*$/';
$replace = '$1';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row['description'];
}

foreach($data as $datas)
{
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $datas) . '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

all this does is return no matches, but if I copy those results and put them in an array it works fine and I know it's not the regex because I tested that before I got this far. Here is an example of the items working when I define them in a seperate array:

```
$subject = array(
  "Suzuki DR100 ignition pickup. Wires to the coils have been repaired and one needs to be repaired again. 082862 S15 <img src = \">http://www.roofis27.com/motorcycle/12_08_28/061.JPG\">",
  "1997 Suzuki VZ800 Marauder, Kick stand and spring. Chrome on end is starting to chip. 0121103 S19 <img src = \">http://www.roofis27.com/motorcycle/13_01_21/103.JPG\">",
  "Honda 1982 VF750C Magna right-side radiator trim panel. Good, damage-free condition. Needs cut and polished. Cheap, fast shipping! 011425 H6 <img src=\">http://www.roofis27.com/motorcycle/10_01_14/030.JPG\"> n=\">",
 ); 

foreach ($subject as $subjects)
{
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subjects) . '<br>';
}
```

Returns:

```
082862 S15

0121103 S19

011425 H6
```

So my question is how can i use `preg_replace()` on an array returned from `mysql_fetch_array()`?

or how else can you search and replace these codes within MySQL.

**Just so I'm sure to make myself clear this time:**
I have a MySQL database that has these location codes within the product_description, they are all  right before the `<img>` tag within a long product description. I need them placed into the the model column of the database, which is in another table. I have no problem using SQL to do this, but cannot get these location codes removed from the description & by themselves. MySQL does not allow regex to be used this way that i am aware of so I'm trying to do it with php instead.
Any help please! I'm really stuck.....

Comment: thats one weird pattern

Comment: Use bracelets for multiple items. Like `([0-9]{6}\s\D\d|[0-9]{4}\s\D[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{6}\s\D\[0-9]{2})`

Comment: Also it's pretty unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to extract that pattern only from `$row['description']`. I have a database with over 20,000 of these descriptions. They come from table named `product_description` In every description I need to remove that pattern then `JOIN` it to another table. If this is still unclear I can show the rest of the code but I'm just trying to figure out how to get `preg_replace()` to work with an array of items.

Comment: I have searched and tried everything i can think of and `preg_replace()` doesn't seem to work on arrays returned from `mysql_fetch_array()`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After talking to some people, apparently there are characters in the return from `mysql_fetch_array()` that are invisible and that's why the regexp does not work. I got way better results using `preg_match()` as follows:

```
foreach($data as $datas)
{

    $pattern = '([0-9]{6}\s\D[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{6}\s\D\d|[0-9]{7}\s\D[0-9]{2})';
    preg_match($pattern, $datas, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    foreach($matches as $match){
        echo $match[0] . '<br>';
    }

}
```